# Batch FOR loop TYPE vs. no TYPE

Tags: windows, batch-file

What is the correct method?  Or, is there a correct method?

We see at:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/sharemig_nt.txt as an example..

```
:: Read the list of shares to be migrated and generate the required batch files
FOR /F "skip=4 tokens=1" %%A IN ('TYPE "%~dp0%ComputerName%_netshares.txt" 2^>NUL ^| FINDSTR.EXE /R /B /I /V /C:"The command completed successfully\." ^| FINDSTR.EXE /R /B /V /C:" " ^| SORT') DO CALL :ReadShare %%A
```

Have also used successfully:

```
SET servers=%CD%\monitored_computers.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1-2* delims=," %%A IN (%servers%) DO (
    SET SERVERNAME=%%A
    SET IP=%%B
)
```

is there a reason to use the TYPE versus "streaming" the content of the Text file?

Specifically:

```
IN ('TYPE "%~dp0%ComputerName%_netshares.txt"...
```

And, yes I understand that the TYPE, TYPEs or what *NIX world would CAT or concatenate the content of a file to screen or re-directed to another file for further processing..

Versus

```
IN (%servers%) DO...
```

Which pretty much does the same thing.  Right?

Thanks!

Comment: in the first example, you are parsing the output of a command, in the second, a file. that's obviously a fundamental difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much.

I believe you'll find however that if there's no newline terminating the file, `TYPE` will conveniently add one for you.

Comment: This is helpful especially dealing with files that were generated in *NIX or with *NIX encoding.  I have read about this a number of times over the past few days.  Great answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental difference between

```
for /F "options..." %%a in (fileName.txt) do ...
```

vs.

```
for /F "options..." %%a in ('type fileName.txt') do ...
```

In the first case the "fileName.txt" is open by the FOR command, that just reads its lines from it. In the second case the FOR command *starts a new internal cmd.exe session*, pass to it the "type fileName.txt" command, redirects cmd.exe output into a temporary file, reads its lines from this redirected file, and finally the temporary file is removed. If this FOR command is placed inside another one that executes it a *large* number of times, the difference in elapsed time may be notorious!

When the additional features of FOR /F command are not required ("tokens, delims, etc"), it is a waste of resources to use it instead of the basic features or plain FOR command. For example:

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do ...
```

vs.

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do ...
```

The same observations of previous case apply here: the first FOR get the file names by itself, but the second one requires another cmd.exe session. Of course, if these commands are used now and then, don't matters which one is used; the problem is when people starts to write large Batch programs using the worst method from efficiency point of view because is the method they used to use...

Another similar issue happens when

```
for /F "options..." %%a in ('type fileName.txt ^| find "etc"') do ...
```

is used instead of

```
for /F "options..." %%a in ('find "etc" ^< fileName.txt') do ...
```

because the redirection is performed in a more efficient way than the pipe, that requires an additional cmd.exe session for each side of the pipe!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have answered my own question:

If you do the following:

```
SET settings=D:\tomcat\conf\server.xml
FOR /F %%A IN ('%settings% ^| find "<Connector port="') DO (
echo %%A
)

pause
```

When run from the server, it opens the xml file in Internet Explorer.  Which of course, is not correct.

Versus:

```
SET settings=D:\tomcat\conf\server.xml
FOR /F %%A IN ('TYPE %settings% 2^> ^| find "<Connector port="') DO (
echo %%A
)

pause
```

This one produces results.

So, in this example, you need to TYPE or pipe through the settings file to search the results you need versus looking through an list of systems.  It really depends on what you need to do do with the list you need to parse through.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `FOR /F %%A IN ('%settings% ^| find "<Connector port="') DO (` have an error. It should be: `FOR /F %%A IN ('^< %settings% find "<Connector port="') DO (`. A pipe is used with _processes_ and a redirection with _files_.